# Back to iOS application automatically when it's suspending in background.

Tags: ios, swift, sms

I have a question,

I work on a Swift 3 project with Xcode.

My goal is to send an alert sms, 20 secondes after receiving a local notification. when I'm in application, every things work well, but when my app is in background, it can do other tasks, like print some character, or play music, or send a text to a socket server, but it can't send the sms.

I think, when I receive an alert, if I could back to my application automatically, then I can send an alert sms, that's why I'm doing this stupide idea and looking for a way to know how I can wake up automatically my application and go back to the first View Controller Screen when I receive a Local Notification?

Maybe there is someone who knows a method to return to the iOS application automatically?

Comment: Dont think you can, the user must touch the notification first to wake your app, then only can process to your viewcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your app is launched into the background—usually to handle some type of background event—the launch cycle changes slightly as given in the picture below. The main difference is that instead of your app being made active, it enters the background state to handle the event and may be suspended at some point after that. When launching into the background, the system still loads your app’s user interface files but it does not display the app’s window.

[image]

Reference - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html

Answer (score 0):

Bringing your app from background to foreground is not possible. And even if you are able to do so, App store will reject it.

Hope it helps!